# TCP Package Forging within AWS VPC

Tags: security, networking, tcp, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I want to utilize AWS VPC to simulate computer security vulnerabilities. This will purely be done from within the VPC internally. Basically an employee uses SSH or Remote Desktop to connect an EC2 instance within the VPC and then performs penetration testing against another EC2 instance, located within the same VPC.

By putting sufficient security measures in place I can make sure that no communication leaks out the VPC, at least as long the TPC packages weren't tampered with.

Now, I wonder whether the network traffic within the AWS VPC is encapsulated enough so that TCP header forging would not affect other AWS customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely encapsulated.  This video from the AWS re:Invent conference describes the system well: [A Day in the Life of a Billion Packets (CPN401) | AWS re:Invent 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd5hsL-JNY4).  Discussion of the mapping service starts around 18 minutes in.